# Timestamp analysis Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataset which looks something like this:

```
ID      DATE       TAG
S3800   1999-07-02 D
S1190   1999-07-02 C
S3131   1999-07-02 C
S3131   1999-07-04 C
S3131   1999-07-05 D
```

I am trying to calculate the minimum and maximum time gap between records for each ID(in days). For example:

```
ID    MIN_TIME_GAP MAX_TIME_GAP 
S3131 1            3
```

The column DATE is in format datetine64[ns]. How do I achieve this in Pandas?

Comment: Why is MIN_TIME_GAP of `S3131` `2`? Between 1999-07-05 and 1999-07-04 is one day, no?

Comment: Yeah sorry my bad, just a calculation error on my part. Edited to reflect it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
# if they aren't sorted already:
df = df.sort_values(by="DATE")

x = df.groupby("ID").agg(
    MIN_TIME_GAP=("DATE", lambda x: np.min(x.diff())),
    MAX_TIME_GAP=("DATE", lambda x: x.max() - x.min()),
)
print(x.dropna())
```

Prints:

```
      MIN_TIME_GAP MAX_TIME_GAP
ID                             
S3131       1 days       3 days
```

---

EDIT: To convert Timedeltas to days:

```py
# convert to days:
x["MIN_TIME_GAP"] = x["MIN_TIME_GAP"].dt.days
x["MAX_TIME_GAP"] = x["MAX_TIME_GAP"].dt.days
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
       MIN_TIME_GAP  MAX_TIME_GAP
ID                               
S3131             1             3
```

Comment: and convert tiemdeltas to days

Comment: @jezrael I've added it :)